# Missing interface elements in htop

Tags: user-interface, interface, putty, htop

After reinstalling the system (on client) had a problem with the interface htop.
Not show some of the elements: username, load average

client: win7pro, putty 9708

server: ubuntu server 12.04

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Putty is rendering "gray" color (sometimes referred to as "bright black") as black. Go to the Putty settings and tweak the colors, it should fix it.

Comment: I found that I needed to change the setting `Indicate bolded text by changing` to `Both`, with no need to change any other colour settings.

Comment: Found that the same fix that @paradroid suggested worked for me too.  Did wonders for improving the visibility of my shell colors as well!

Comment: @paradroid Version 0.64 (2015-02-08) changelog: Bug fix: reset the bolded-text default setting back to what it used to be. (0.63 set it to something wrong, as a side effect of refactoring.)  It seems to default to "The colour".

Comment: I had the same problem with OS X 10.11.4 with Terminal.app and stumbled upon this question. This fixed it for me: going to the 'Terminal.app' preferences, 'Profiles' tab, enable 'Use bright colors for bold text' checkbox

Answer (score 8):

There are two common ways to render ANSI "bold" text: as actual bold characters, or as light-colored text.  Modern Linux tools tend to expect the latter, but PuTTY uses the former.  As @paradroid said, you can configure how PuTTY handles ANSI bold codes.  I tend to keep it on color-only, but if you also use programs that expect bold to literally mean bold, you may want to choose `Both`.

**Update:**

PuTTY has been updated with better defaults.  If you're seeing bold text without light coloring, you may want to consider updating PuTTY.